# Relationship eloquent in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In `user`:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

In `post`:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
}
```

I handle in controller:

```
$user = Users::find('1')->posts;
```

Then I get an array and the result returned is exactly what I need.

But when I query this way because I need to get a lot of data, the result is an empty array. What did I do wrong?

In `UserController.php`:

```
$listUser = Users::with('posts')
    ->select('name', 'title')
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->get(); // It returns posts as an empty array
```

Please give me any comments.

Comment: I think you must include `id` in your `select` otherwise it won't know how to get the related posts

Comment: can you dump the raw query?

Comment: You need to select in this way `select('users.id','users.name', 'posts.title')....`

Comment: Hi Miedkes, to improve the chance of receiving a good answer, I'd suggest you look at the [how to ask tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again. Specifically, you should make sure to summarize your question in the title and provide all relevant details (database structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `foreign key` in `posts`:

```
$listUser = Users::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->with(['posts' => function($query) {
        $query->select(['user_id','title']);
    }])
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->get();
```

or

```
$result = User::select(['id', 'name'])
    ->with(['posts:user_id, title'])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your relation is developed with a primary key and in your query you are missing the `id` to get the values.

```
$listUser = Users::with('posts')
    ->select('users.id', 'users.name', 'posts.title')
    ->where('posts.type', 1)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to select only some fields of the related model you can specify it in the `with` clause like the following. The select clause will work on the `User` query builder.

```
$listUser = Users::with('posts:user_id, title')
    ->select('name')
    ->where('type', 1)
    ->get();
```